# необходимо посчитать значениях всех value, что содержат определенное имя или класс

Tags: javascript, html, windows, веб-программирование

Сложение значений из select , которые были selected пользователем.
То есть необходимо посчитать значениях всех value, что содержат определенное имя или класс, то есть необходимо сложить все select'ы, которые были selected пользователем. Я, наверное, непонятно объясняю, поэтому лучше покажу код.

```js
function calc() {
var group = document.getElementById("group1");

var sum = 0;
sum += parseInt(group.options[group1.selectedIndex].value);

result.innerHTML = sum;
 }
  
  
  
  
  /* ВОТ ТАКАЯ ФИГНЯ
  Скрипт считает значения только из первого селекта, а мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы он считал значения со всех селектов, что содержат имя select или класс mda
  
  Как это можно реализовать? */
```

```html
<select id="group1" class="mda" name="select" onchange="calc()">
<option value="0">ничего не выбрано</option>
<option value="500">какая-то фигня</option>
<option value="800">вторая фигня</option>
</select>

<select id="group2" class="mda" name="select" onchange="calc()">
<option value="0">ничего не выбрано</option>
<option value="700">продолжение фигни</option>
<option value="1200">снова фигня</option>
</select>

<select id="group3" class="mda" name="select" onchange="calc()">
<option value="20">ничего не выбрано</option>
<option value="500">продолжение фигни</option>
<option value="12200">снова фигня</option>
</select>

<h1><div style="text-align:center;" id="result"></div></h1>
```

Comment: Ваша функция обращается только к первому id...

Comment: Я это знаю, поэтому я спрашиваю, как реализовать сложение по тэгу Name Select или по классу Mda. Мне это нужно, потому что таких select'ов могут быть сотни. Не буду я ведь к каждому по id обращаться?

Comment: Ну так Вас никто и не заставляет обращаться по id,можно по любому селектору(queryselectorall) и после пройтись по массиву

Comment: пример не дадите? Пожалуйста, я уже все мозги убил, не знаю, как реализовать. Я и по циклу пытался и по массиву, но руки не с того места, к сожалению... :(

Comment: const arr = document.querySelectorAll(".mda");
const calc = arr => Array.from(arr).reduce((acc,it) => parseInt(it.value))
console.log(calc(arr))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function calc() {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('select').length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName('select')[i].getAttribute('name') == 'select' || 
        document.getElementsByTagName('select')[i].classList.contains('mda')) {
      sum += parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName('select')[i].value);
    }
  }

  result.innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<select id="group1" class="mda" name="select" onchange="calc()">
  <option value="0">ничего не выбрано</option>
  <option value="500">какая-то фигня</option>
  <option value="800">вторая фигня</option>
</select>

<select id="group2" class="mda" name="select" onchange="calc()">
  <option value="0">ничего не выбрано</option>
  <option value="700">продолжение фигни</option>
  <option value="1200">снова фигня</option>
</select>

<select id="group3" class="mda" name="select" onchange="calc()">
  <option value="20">ничего не выбрано</option>
  <option value="500">продолжение фигни</option>
  <option value="12200">снова фигня</option>
</select>

<h1>
  <div style="text-align:center;" id="result"></div>
</h1>
```

Comment: друг, ты меня спас! огромное спасибо!)))